# How to convert a string with C type placeholders (%d, %x etc.) in C#

Tags: c#, c, string

I need to insert variables into the placeholders of a C string type. I need to do it in C#. (i know in Java it works with the String.format)
Note that i don't know how many variables, and what types to expect.
I get the originalString string! can't change the format to the C# convention.
examlpe:

```
   string originalString= "this is my number %d";
   int myNumber = 3;
   string result= string.Format(originalString, myNumber);//This doesn't work in C#!
```

Comment: As far as I know there's nothing in .NET that will do that kind of formatting. If you have a very limited set of format specifiers you need to support you can probably use a regular expression or basic string replacement, but otherwise you're going to need something general enough.

Comment: Is this .NET Framework on Windows, .NET Core? .NET Standard?

Answer (score 2):

In order to *match* and then replace `%d`, `%i` and the like consructions, you can try *regular expressions*. The simplest (just a substitution) code can be

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

private static string MyFormat(string source, params object[] args) {
  int index = 0;

  return Regex.Replace(source, "%[isdf]", match => args[index++]?.ToString());
}
```

And then

```
string result = MyFormat(
  "this is my number %d next number is %d and string is %s", 3, 5, "STR");

Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
this is my number 3 next number is 5 and string is STR
```

If you want not just to replace `%d`, `%i` ect. but implement some *elaborated logic* you can use the code below:

```
private static string MyFormat(string source, params object[] args) {
  int index = 0;

  return Regex.Replace(source, "%[sdfx]", match => {
    string pattern = match.Value.TrimStart('%'); // "s", "d", "x" and the like
    object value = args[index++];                // 3, 5, STR etc

    //TODO: apply special logic here and return the formatted value
    return value.ToString();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use

```
string originalString = "this is my number {0}";
int myNumber = 3;
string result= string.Format(originalString, myNumber);
```

the result will be = "this is my number 3"

Answer (score -1):

If you are compiling this for Windows you can use p/invoke to call a version of sprintf available through msvcrt.dll. You will need this file to be present on your system.

Declare this method somewhere:

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", SetLastError = false,
 CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int sprintf(StringBuilder buff, string format, __arglist);
```

Then call it like this, you might want to create a wrapper method for it:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(256); // 256 needs to be high enough to encapsulate the final result in number of characters + 1 at the least
sprintf(sb, "this is my number %d", __arglist(3));
// sb.ToString() will now return "this is my number 3"
```